# What capacitor is required for a 6 V DC motor running on a 12 V power supply?

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor

For my school project, I am building a car powered by a 6 V DC motor running on a 12 V power supply. In order to prevent wheelspin at the start of the track, it has been recommended to add a capacitor so that the motor isn't instantly flooded with the full 12 V. I want to have just a fraction of a second of delay so that it doesn't affect my speed too much.

However, I am unsure what type of capacitor to use and how large it should be. Sorry, I have little electronics knowledge as this is one of my first experiences with it.

Comment: I think a capacitor is not what you need ,Think some more and edit your question and then you will get good answers.

Answer (score 4):

> *I am building a car powered by a 6v DC motor running on a 12v power
> supply. In order to prevent wheelspin at the start of the track, it
> has been recommended to add a capacitor so that the motor isn't
> instantly flooded with the full 12v.*

That won't work. You need to use a pulse width modulated controller that converts the 12 volts into 6 volts and does so with a smooth transition on first activating the motor. You can probably find a buck regulator circuit off the shelf that can do this for you.

Comment: I am not trying to convert the current from 12v to 6v, I just want it to be low power to start with and then back to maximum power so that I can have maximum speed.

Comment: @AmmarSyed you under-estimate the implications of your requirements. For a start you cannot run a 6 volt motor on 12 volts without it burning fairly quickly and secondly, a capacitor on its own doesn't help irrespective of recommendations. Those recommendations are incorrect.

Comment: It will only be running for seconds at a time and I'm not even sure if the motor is 6v, it might be 12v.

Comment: This is an engineering site and maybes and not sures are not the currency we use. You can't design stuff on maybes and not sures.

Comment: Can you forget about the rest of it and try to answer how large of a capacitor I would need to slow start my motor to avoid wheelspin?

Comment: A capacitor is wrong; it won't work on it's own and is not protecting your motor. I'm not going to give bad advice.

Comment: I'm not trying to protect the motor as the motor being used and the power supply is out of my control, that is up to my teacher. I'm trying to ease into max speed to avoid wheelspin at the start of the track.

Comment: Then just do as your teacher says and ignore good advice or, point out this answer to your teacher and convince him he's wrong. Either way, I'm not compromising my answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry to pester you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> it has been recommended to add a capacitor so that the motor isn't instantly flooded with the full 12v

Wherever you got that advice from - I'd say avoid that place :)

It is not technically wrong, in the same way as "a good solution to the river flooding problem is to pump the water through pipes and dump it elsewhere" is not technically wrong. It's "true" but tell that to a person who is being flooded  by a river and they'll just shake their head.

Yes, a huge capacitor would "work". But not in any way other than a lab curiosity, or a museum exhibit. It won't work in any application with practical constraints.

There are exceptions, but in general: a 6V-rated DC motor will die when powered continuously from 12V. So the primary problem isn't even startup, but the steady state. At 12V and nominal RPM, the rotor core may well be saturating, excessive currents will flow, the windings will overheat, damage their insulation, and fail shorted or open if the wire heats locally enough to burn out.

12V will be OK if the motor runs at a much higher RPM, since the back-EMF will reduce the effective voltage across windings. But then you'll be overspeeding that poor motor. The commutator will also experience excessive wear at twice the rated operating voltage. At the higher voltage, the arcs will sustain longer, and do more damage.

Comment: It will only be running for seconds at a time and I'm not even sure if the motor is 6v, it might be 12v.